# Cant install Ubuntu alongside Windows

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I know that this question is very known but I didn't find any saner for my particular case.

The problem is that the option of install Ubuntu alongside windows is not showing at the installation.

I understand that the problem is that the space which I allocated is not usable And then I understand that it's maybe because that I have already 4 partitions but I didn't found an answer that solve the problem. I will be for your help.

Thank you very much.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Ubuntu will not create partitions .
-c/f free installation space is being stated as 78% of 296.13 GB available.

If Windows 10-- chose (click on)  C  partition -right click and "Shrink Volume..."
Set the amount of space to shink -eg 30GB -windows will then call this new space unallocated--and possibly name "D", "E" or similar .

Right click the new space --then FORMAT as NTFS--and now the partition .
is ready to install Ubuntu.

Windows will create the dual boot automatically.
All Window systems since Win 7 have this procedure--to replace that only third party software would create dual boot. cheer.

Comment: May apply ---"You need to have Windows fast start up or always on hibernation off. The Linux NTFS driver will not mount hibernated NTFS partitions so installer cannot even see that you have Windows".

Comment: This answer is incorrect and contains factual inaccuracies.  The Ubiquity installer for Ubuntu will absolutely create partitions as long as there is un-partitioned space.  In fact, this is how the guided "Install Alongside Windows" option works.  The unallocated space should be left as unallocated for the best results. Also, Ubuntu can not be installed on a NTFS partition.  NTFS is a Microsoft proprietary file system that does not support Linux file permissions, which is required for an Ubuntu installation.